# Error: Cannot find 'expo-modules-autolinking' package in your project, make sure that you have 'expo' package installed, Eas Build

Tags: react-native, npm, deployment, expo, eas

Version installed :

```
Node : v18.17.1
Eas : eas-cli/5.0.2 win32-x64 node-v18.17.1
{
"expo": "^49.0.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.4",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.3",
}
```

i used to build new Versions of my App using EAS Build Command, but After updating all the packages, Node, Eas, Expo. i'm getting an Error while Building Using expo and EAS.

**Error :**

> Error: Cannot find 'expo-modules-autolinking' package in your project,
> make sure that you have 'expo' package installed

i tried Command **"npx expo-doctor"** and it shows me that **everything is OK** Except one Warning i dont think its related :

> WARNING: We recommend using PowerShell or Bash via WSL 2 for
> development with Expo CLI on Windows. You may encounter issues using
> cmd.exe.

- i Also tried installing that Package "expo-modules-autolinking" but
  the expo-doctor shows me that there's a conflict of that package
- i Also tried Overrides it in Package.json but still getting Error

This is the complete Error i got on the console of Expo build dashboard:

```
✖ Config sync failed

[stderr] 

Error: Cannot find 'expo-modules-autolinking' package in your project, make sure that you have 'expo' package installed

[stderr] 

Error: Cannot find 'expo-modules-autolinking' package in your project, make sure that you have 'expo' package installed

[stderr] 

    at tryRequireExpoModulesAutolinking (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config/build/importExpoModulesAutolinking.js:24:11)

[stderr] 

    at importExpoModulesAutolinking (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config/build/importExpoModulesAutolinking.js:13:23)

[stderr] 

    at getAutolinkedPackagesAsync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config/build/getAutolinkedPackages.js:24:88)

[stderr] 

    at Object.getPrebuildConfigAsync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config/build/getPrebuildConfig.js:29:91)

[stderr] 

    at configureProjectAsync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/prebuild/configureProjectAsync.js:45:56)

[stderr] 

    at async prebuildAsync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/prebuild/prebuildAsync.js:88:9)

npx expo prebuild --no-install --platform android exited with non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

after running the below command, I was able to prebuild.

```
 npx expo prebuild --platform android  --clean
```

deleting your Android, ios folder and prebuild again should also do the trick.